# How computer name property is identified in LDAP? (active directory)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Using .net, I'm trying to pull info from this AD field: Computer Name(pre-Windows 2000). However, I don't know what the property identifier for it is.

For instance, if you want to look for the city property, you use "l". I'm wondering what the corresponding identifier is for computer name.

```
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("l"); //load city property
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("?"); //what is computer name?
```

Does anyone know what to use here? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The AD ldap attribute for the pre-Windows 2000 computer name is "sAMAccountName". I verified it myself on AD by creating a bogus computer account, giving it a unique pre-win 2000 name, and then checking the AD attributes using [LDAP Admin](http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

In our environment both of these return the computer name but I can't tell which is tied to Computer Name(pre-Windows 2000).

```
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the identifier was "employeeID".

Comment: You might want to consider accepting your answer (indicates to other what was the solution)

Comment: @Ted Are you sure that is correct? Or did it turn out you needed an entirely different attribute for your requirements?